# html runtime create code very slow

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, caching, client-side

I made a spreadsheet 
example image
http://www.jqwidgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/jquery-spreadsheet.png

this my total datas (3974 rows) ( I am using entitiy Mvc 4 c# / framework 4.5 store procedure) no join single table and I'am using LOCALHOST) mssql 2014 express
but I'm very waiting ( only html create ) no data  ( avarage 2 minutes only load) and when I click on  cell(input) Waiting for 8 seconds

3.794 rows coming fast from the server only html create slow

How can I speed it up? if it is not possible..
or Can you are recommend me a spreadsheet?
or client side cache or mvc data cache Which helpful?
thank you

```
function GridEstimation() {

var estimationModel = GetEstimations();  3.974 ROWS
var GridEstimation = document.getElementById('GridEstimation');

var dynamicNav = "";
if (estimationModel != "undefined") {

    dynamicNav += '<div class="table-wrapper">';
    dynamicNav += '<div class="table-scroll">';
    dynamicNav += '<table class="tftable" border="1">';
```

> 24 VESSEL ROWS

```
    dynamicNav += '<tr>'
    dynamicNav += '<th>Invoice Item</th>' 
    for (var i = 0; i < estimationModel.Vessels.length; i++) { 

        dynamicNav += '<th id=' + estimationModel.Vessels[i].VesselID + '>' + estimationModel.Vessels[i].VesselName + '</th>'

    }
    dynamicNav += '</tr>'
```

> 158 ITEM(stock) ROWS

```
    for (var m = 0; m < estimationModel.Items.length; m++) {

      dynamicNav += '<tr>';
        dynamicNav += '<td>' + estimationModel.Items[m].InvoiceItemName + '</td>';
```

> 3.792 CELL INPUT ROWS

```
  for (var n = 0; n < estimationModel.Estimations.length; n++) {
            dynamicNav += '<div><input type="text" id=' + estimationModel.Estimations[n].EstimationID + '/></div>';

        }

        dynamicNav += '</tr>'
    }

    dynamicNav += '</tr>'
    dynamicNav += '</table>'
    dynamicNav += '</div>';
    dynamicNav += '</div>';
} 

$("#GridEstimation").append(dynamicNav);
```

}

Comment: Have you verified that the Javascript code is the bottleneck and not the server-side code somewhere? Also, that's a really long list of data, you could change it to use server-side paging to only load a few at a time.

Comment: you cannot load that many rows into memory and expect it to be graceful. I would consider looking at your design overall or think about implementing infinite scroll or something similar. You need to be looking at destroying dom objects that aren't on screen. Memory is your enemy here

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons, this might go very slowly is that you are creating potentially a large HTML string and concatenating it part by part. The following example could improve this drastically http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12375/JavaScript-StringBuilder .

Even better approach would then be to just render the HTML gradually (in the while loops), not all at once in one huge HTML string.

Comment: hello thank you every body 
I think to use the data cache but
Do not use my method parameters and
I want used VaryByParam What should I do?


 [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "VesselID")]
 GetVessels();

Comment: In case the actual output is generated on the client and as you mentioned, the server-side is not the source of your performance issue, then you really need to concentrate on the JavaScript side of things and make sure to optimize the code there. Also, caching output will not help, when most of the markup is generated by JS.